# Searching and editing nested JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json, search

Basically I want to be able, in Javascript (JQuery optionally), to search into a JSON with nested elements for a particular element and edit it.

Ex. search for "components" with id 110 and change the name to "video card".

Notice the following JSON is just an example. I am wondering if javascript libraries or good tricks exist to do such a thing, I don't think traversing the whole json or writing my own methods is the best solution.

```
{
   "computers": [
   {
     "id": 10,
     "components": [
         {
           "id": 56,
           "name": "processor"
         },
         {
           "id": 24,
           "name": "ram"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "components": [
        {
          "id": 110,
          "name": "graphic card"
        },
        {
          "id": 322,
          "name": "motherboard"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Traversing the object is the ***only*** option. All answers you get here will do that one way or another.

Comment: Ok, but I believe libraries exist already to do such a thing, in particular not just searching inside the JSON but also allowing me to actually edit it.

Comment: Just to get it out of the way: By the time you're searching it, it's no longer JSON; it's just an object graph.

Comment: So basically, you're looking for a library that does the equivalent of what jQuery does with CSS selectors, or what XPath does for XML documents. You give a path, and it matches it against a specific structure. Not a bad idea...

Comment: Exactly, even if it becomes an object graph then I would need to turn it into JSON again.

Comment: @Fr4ncis: Why? Are you sending it somewhere? (For instance, for storage in a document database?) JSON is a **textual** representation for transporting or storing data.

Comment: Ok, long story short I have json data used with templates to render HTML, then I store the JSON for caching purposes and I want to be able to modify it offline, therefore I need the JSON representation modified and I cannot modify directly the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I've used linq.js to significant extent, and although a little wordy, it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript lib, DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com), with which you can filter matches using XPath on JSON structures. To put it in JS code:

```
var data = {
       "computers": [
          {
             "id": 10,
             "components": [
                { "id": 56, "name": "processor" },
                { "id": 24, "name": "ram" }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id": 11,
             "components": [
                { "id": 110, "name": "graphic card" },
                { "id": 322, "name": "motherboard" }
             ]
          }
       ]
    },
    res = JSON.search( data, '//components[id=110]' );

res[0].name = 'video card';
```

Here is a working fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/g8fZw/

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and returns an array with matches (empty array if no matches were found). You can try out the lib and XPath queries using the XPath Evaluator here:

http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator